# PHP class value with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, oop

Is it possible to get an PHP class variable with Ajax on load ? My class is called when submit is clicked and I was wondering if there is any way I can get the value in alert box when the loading is done ?

EDIT:

```
class VacationCalc {
    ......

  function VacationLeft($date) {
    $someValue = (strtotime($date) - strtotime($this->worker->vacationStartDate)) / 86400;
    $rest = $someValue - $this->vacationWithoutPay;
    echo $this->leftDays = number_format($this->worker->daysInyear + ($rest * ($this->worker->vacationDaysInYear / 365.25)) - $this->daysAllreadyDone,1,',',' ');

    }
  }
}
```

I would like to get the value to an alert box after loading is done.

Comment: Yeah you can! Glad I could answer your question :)

Comment: What do you mean by Class value?

Comment: You should work on your terminology in order to clarify things and not confuse people. There is nothing like a *class value*, and a class cannot be *run*. Some code was nice, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the page as any other page you would withou AJAX, but only echoing the desired output.

Than you can call the result via AJAX without a problem.

Comment: How do you make your normal (not AJAX) pages?

Comment: I know that part, the page is done..The thing I need to know is how to show the result from a php class in an alert box.

Comment: So your question is: "How to call a page via AJAX?". This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103055/jquery-ajax-and-php-classes?rq=1 and this http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+class+php